# How do I port this Objective-C idiom to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C, I'd frequently end up with code like this:

```
if( ! [self.delegate respondsToSelector(shouldSelectItem:)] || 
    [self.delegate shouldSelectItem: item] ) {
  // ..
}
```

Basically, if the delegate implements `shouldSelectItem`, then I call that method to find out if I should proceed with the logic inside the if statement. If it doesn't, then I continue into the if statement by default.

In Swift, I've so far achieved the same with the following:

```
if self.delegate?.shouldSelectItem?(item) ?? true {
  // ...
}
```

If the delegate doesn't implement the method, the left operand of the expression is nil, so the `??` operator will return true. This is shorter, but seems somewhat awkward to me. Is there a better way to express this concept in Swift?

Comment: What is "awkward" about your second method? I would have no problem with it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the vote of confidence. Maybe it's okay as is.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you have also  the check 'respondsToSelector':

```
if self.delegate?.respondsToSelector(Selector("shouldSelectItem:")) {
    ... do your works            

}
```

Comment: That's not the preferred way to do it in Swift.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_428

Comment: So just use the check ?? true or != nil if you prefer Swift way

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of:

```
if( ! [self.delegate respondsToSelector(shouldSelectItem:)] || [self.delegate shouldSelectItem: item] ) {
```

is:

```
if self.delegate?.shouldSelectItem == nil || self.delegate!.shouldSelectItem!(item) {
```

But I prefer **your** solution :)

Comment: Minor nitpicking: `if self.delegate?.shouldSelectItem == nil` actually *calls* the property getter (if available), whereas `if( ! [self.delegate respondsToSelector(shouldSelectItem:)]` only checks the availability. Should make no difference unless the getter method has side effects ...

Comment: Moreover, this method cannot handle overloaded functions. e.g. `tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:section:)` and `tableView(_:willDisplayFooterView:section:)`